# how to keep calling the api until the result is retrieved in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a api which i need to keep calling it until the result is ready to fetch

```
SendToBank(){

 this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`).subscribe(s=>{

 this.qrcodelink=s["qrCodeLink"];

 });
```

qrCodeLink is the property inside my result which i need it,it has other properties as well ,sometimes after 5 seconds result is there sometimes 10 seconds but i need to put a loader in my front end and keep calling it until i get the result ,any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the observable to retry the request. You can use an interval or a maximum number of retries:

```js
this.http.get("`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`")
  .pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
    return interval(5000)
  }))
  .subscribe(result => ...)
}
```

Or better practice:

```js
this.http.get("`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`")
  .pipe(
    retry(3),
    catchError(() => { // Handle error
      ...
    }),
    ... // Some more pipes
  )
  .subscribe(result => ...)
}
```

Anything other than the retry is optional of course, you can pipe through anything you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval with a time period of your choice and call the api inside its subscription along with checking if the api response is what you need. If the response is what you need, you can unsubscribe from the interval.